Parsing a source code with just one digit
Could some please walk me through, how CPython parses a file contain just one character 1?
In particular, why ast.parse("3") returns ...Expr(...)... as (I believe) Python's source code is a list of statements?
In other words, reading the grammar how do I go from file to ... atom (I guess)?

An expression can also be a statement.

@bereal Could you please point me to the relevant rule in the grammar?

An expression can also be a statement, the rule sequence is:
file -> statements -> statement -> 
    simple_stmts -> simple_stmt -> star_expressions -> star_expression -> 
    expression

After all, func(x) is also an expression, and a file print('Hello world!') is perfectly valid.

Ah, the star_expresions rule, thanks a lot!
